# apportable : No module named argparse error on mac

Tags: macos, installation, apportable

i just installed apportable from here : http://www.apportable.com/users/1928
now , after installing successfully it gives this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macintosh/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 3, in 
    import argparse
ImportError: No module named argparse

i can understand it's import issue .. but i am not able to resolve this .. can anyone help on this !! i have tried this for many times & still same error .. what could be the possible resolution to this. 
please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an old python. You should have version 2.7+:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

Or old MacOS X. Apportable requires Mac OS X 10.7+.

Comment: Beusterein .. exactly ..i have this :Python 2.6.1
so how can i update my python version ...

Comment: i successfully update my python using installer from this link : http://www.python.org/getit/

Comment: : have you worked on apportable .. i am having one more building error :                                         Macintoshs-iMac:Spin macintosh$ apportable build
Building to /Users/macintosh/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug
Error: Could not find file /Users/macintosh/.apportable/SDK/toolchain/macosx

Comment: Do you have at least OS X 10.7. For example - $ sw_vers -productVersion
10.8.2

Comment: my version is ->>  OS X 10.6.8

Comment: As mentioned at http://docs.apportable.com/introduction.html#quick-start, You need to upgrade to at least OS X 10.7 to use Apportable